# mouseMove not working with Selenium and Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor, karma-jasmine

Hi in an Angular application I have an Openlayers3 map on which I have a layer which represents a building. In my test I am trying to click on one of these buildings which triggers a sidepanel with images linked to this building.

The problem is that only in Firefox my test does not seem to work. I was wondering if anyone else has stumbled upon this problem and if their is a solution.

My guess is it has something to do with the `.mouseMove`
my code :

// I have a page object which has a method

```
this.klikOpGebouw = function(gebouwId) {
    return browser.executeScript("return angular.element(document.querySelector('#map')).scope().map.custom.getPixelForGebouw(" + gebouwId + ")").then(function(pixel){
        return browser.actions()
            .mouseMove(element(by.id("map")).getWebElement(), {x: pixel[0], y: pixel[1]})
            .click()
            .perform();
    });
};
```

And in my test I do :

```
it('er zijn verschillende afbeeldingen gekoppeld aan het dossier', function() {
    mainPage.goTo('admin', 'admin');
    var dossierDetailPage = mainPage.dossiers().byIndex(0).openDetail();
    browser.waitForAngular();
    dossierDetailPage.klikOpGebouw(1);
    var gebouwPanel = dossierDetailPage.getGebouwPanel();
    expect(gebouwPanel.countAfbeeldingen()).toBe(3);
});
```

In chrome and internet explorer this works perfectly. Only in Firefox it goes fubar. Any ideas ?

```
Selenium driver : 2.47.1
AngularJS : 1.3.4
karma : 0.12.16
karma-jasmine: 0.2.2
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

This is how we do it. The difference is that we use numbers for our X/Y coordinates, not an object:

```
//select a value with mouse
popup.getLocation().then(function (position) {
   popup.getSize().then(function (dimension) {
      browser.actions().
      mouseMove(popup, 0, 150).
      click().
      perform();
      expect(input.getAttribute('value')).toBe('id_3');                    
   });
});
```

Comment: tried it but no dice. We checked if the pixel that is clicked is in fact the pixel of the building and this seems to be the case. We tried using the openlayers method : forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer){}) method but we are getting zero features from this method for our specified pixel. its puzzling

Comment: ok. The other difference I noticed from our code is that you use getWebElement(). We simply use this: element(by.css('div[some name]')); Don't know if that will help...

Comment: tried that too but no dice. I think it is gonne be something more fundamental. As it is only failing in Firefox